# __vitePreload has "__VITE_PRELOAD__" instead of an empty array dependency

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, vite

I'm running a Vite + React project, everything works perfectly fine when running locally in dev mode, and also under preview. However, when I run the same process on my docker image I can see on the generated bundle that one of the __vitePreload methods has the plain string `"__VITE_PRELOAD__"` instead of an empty array.

What could be causing this? I'm really not that familiarized with the innings of vite and I can't seem to find anything relevant on their github.

Comment: It will help identify the cause of this behavior if you can share the vite configuration.